# How to deal with people editing their answers to incorporate other answers?

Tags: discussion, edits, answers, fastest-gun, attribution

One thing I've noticed on Stack Overflow is that users will often post a first answer to a question falling in to one or more of the following categories:

- Very limited detail/explanation
- No mention of alternative solutions
- An entirely incorrect answer

As other users provide better answers to the question, the original answerer then edits his/her answer to achieve one or more of the following:

- Incorporate extra detail given in other answers
- Add different options/opinions as given in other answers
- Correct their initial answer by changing it to a completely different solution

The purpose of this seems to be to accumulate upvotes by having the best answer to the question at any given moment either by being the only one, or ripping off other answers as they are posted.

Other than downvoting an answer that is actually correct, are there any other options?

Comment: Welcome to the [Fastest Gun In The West problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem) and [it's follow up](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73/is-the-fastest-gun-in-the-west-solved)

Comment: You are quite gracious.  I would be tempted to be a bit more direct and ask this as **How do I keep competitors from plagiarizing and stealing rep credit for my fast, correct, short, simple answer to an easy LMGTFY question?**  However, beware, written this way, it almost answers itself.

Comment: Upvoting works well, as they are creating a good answer for the benefit of everyone.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If the answer is useful and correct (which is implied from it incorporating more information) then you should **not** be downvoting.

There is nothing wrong with someone posting a "quick and dirty" answer that gives an immediate solution and then coming back to flesh it out with more information. As far as Stack Overflow is concerned it is better to have **all** the information in a single answer on a single question so that the next person arriving from Google doesn't have to search the site any further.

What would be wrong is if they are *copying* the other answers without attribution. You can't assume that this is what people have done based on a single answer. It could be that the extra information (from the MSDN or JavaDoc say) is relatively easily discovered and was added independently. In cases like this it would *appear* that the information from one answer was copied into another.

If you think that there is plagiarism going on you would need evidence that the copying is happening on multiple posts, and things like spelling mistakes etc are being copied as well then flag one of the answers for moderator attention.

Comment: Plagiarism generally refers to fairly literal copying though, not simply adopting the same ideas in restated form.  When I've had this happen to an answer of mine, what bothered me most was that the person doing it clearly did not understand the subject matter - in response to each comment pointing out what was wrong with their answer they incorporated the respective part of mine, but not in a way that produced a cohesive result.  To downvote it would have seemed rather petty, but it did illustrate the gap between correcting flaws vs. having a good answer.

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing wrong with improving the quality and completeness of your answer. Particularly if you amend something that's wrong/misleading.

What is wrong is plagiarism - which is passing off someone else's work as your own. Referencing answers as you would other sources is acceptable, although I'd suggest it was impolite if you don't have some significant additional contribution to offer.