# Answer edited to incorporate subsequent answer, and upvoted

Tags: discussion

[How to deal with people editing their answers to incorporate other answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258183/how-to-deal-with-people-editing-their-answers-to-incorporate-other-answers) came up when searching for a duplicate for this, but that is about people cheating by editing their *own* answers, which is not the case here. Rather, the edit came from the querier and clearly with good intentions.

[How to uninstall a plugin from Jenkins (Hudson)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4965235/how-to-uninstall-a-plugin-from-jenkins-hudson) was asked by Jim in Feb 2011, about how to work around the lack of a particular feature in a popular software package. It was [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4965554/12916) soon afterwards by Mark, and as far as I know that was indeed the most appropriate answer at the time.

Much later, I came across this question somehow. The feature had just been implemented by a colleague of mine, so I [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13478007/12916) the question in Nov 2012, noting the new feature and the version in which it had appeared. So far so good.

The next day, Jim (the querier) [edited the older answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4965554/revisions) to incorporate the new information from my answer, giving me credit for it in the comment. [Three out of five reviewers](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1050465) approved the edit, so it went through.

Now it is two years later; according to statistics I have seen, the overwhelming majority of users of the overwhelmingly more popular fork of the project are using a version which includes this feature, so the original workaround is of much less significance. Yet my answer has one upvote, while Mark’s has 57. (I felt obliged to add one of my own since this answer as currently written is the most complete.) I have no apparent access to a full history of the question so I can only speculate about how many of the upvotes came before vs. after the edit.

I am not going to go starving for the lack of reputation, of course, but is this situation appropriate in general, or were the two dissenting reviewers correct? [This advice about plagiarism](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251390/12916) notes that attribution is required, which was given here, but does not mention voting as such.

Comment: I feel like your answer would have been much better suited as a comment on or an edit to the accepted answer in the first place. Perhaps if at the time you'd gone into more detail in your answer then Jim wouldn't have felt the need to update the accepted answer and may have marked your answer as accepted instead.

Comment: Most people who search for this question do so because they are having problems with uninstalling. If the newest version has a simple UI for that, a majority of people having trouble may be using an older version or cannot use the UI for some reason, since otherwise they probably do not need to search for the issue at all. So for the people finding this question, the older answer may be more useful.

Comment: One could argue that you're stealing the answer from your colleague, who actually implemented the feature.

Comment: FYI, you can access the question timeline through a specially crafted url.  It's in the form `/posts/[postid]/timeline`.  In this case: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/4965235/timeline.  You can see on what days various events happened including how many votes were accumulated that day.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your answer, as written, contained useful information.  But it was mainly a link to somewhere else, and it did not solve problems for all users of the package (including the OP when the question was asked).

Creating a more complete answer out of your answer and the original answer was thus a good idea.

Your options included:

1. Ask the original answerer to edit their solution with the new information, or do it yourself.
2. Write an answer focusing on the new feature.  Instead of "it exists" and a link, I'd include instructions on how to use the remove plugins feature.  Then include information on how to solve the problem if you lack the new feature, possibly stealing from the current best answers (with attribution) to make your answer complete.
3. Post the fact that the newest version has a new feature, and let others generate a synthesis, in an answer or a comment.

You in effect went with 3.  Others synthesized, and your answer wasn't where they put the final product.

Comment: Sounds like #2 is probably the right thing to do.

Comment: @JesseGlick 2 plus 3, I'd think.  If the content for 2 is based on the link from 3, then the link should still probably be included in 2.  After all, an answer saying "this is how you'd do this, based on the content at X"                                                                                                                                                                                                                          more context , and in a few years if the answer becomes wrong, it's much clearer that this answer was based on outdated information that probably once worked.

Answer (score 24):

The edit was appropriate. It's good to update old answers with new information so that people searching find the most up-to-date, relevant information about their problem at the top of the page. The only thing that I saw that could be improved was that you really should have been credited in the body of the post. Almost nobody will see the attribution in the revision history. I corrected that.

Comment: I think this answer doesn't address the perceived injustice of the policies that result in him not getting reputation.

Comment: @JoeMurray That's because I don't think it's worth addressing. We can't force people to vote for his answer.

Comment: "Perceived injustice" is the operative term here.

Comment: He's missing out on a few dozen upvotes...oh the humanity!