# Code stolen by highly upvoted, outdated answer

Tags: discussion, plagiarism, attribution, outdated-information

There is a [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) question: [How to prevent form from being submitted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350247/how-to-prevent-form-from-being-submitted/). It has been asked more than five years ago and a lot changed since then. Basically, all the answers recommends using obsolete inline events (`onsubmit` HTML attribute) or assigning event handler to `onsubmit` property of DOM element, which is also not a good idea. I think these answers are bad, so I downvoted them, explained my point in comments (some of them has already been deleted) and posted my own answer.

After a few hours, the author of [the highest-scoring answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3350260/3853934) noticed that his answer is obsolete. However, instead of writing his own solution, he literally copy-pasted the code from my answer to his own, without even giving me any credit. Also, he posted this code as third solution, so most of the users would still read only the first or second solution. I appreciate that he wanted to improve his answer, but I think that:

1. He should write his own code, and possibly give me some credit.
2. He should replace the outdated answer with an up-to-date solution, not add it as an alternative.

What should be done with it?

I think fixing this question is a priority, because it has over 100k views and still a lot of people come there and learn bad coding practices (which also leads to asking new questions containing code following these coding practices).

**Edit:**

The edit on this answer has been rolled back and it also has been made CW, so the problem with stealing my answer has been solved. However, I think that there still is a problem with this answer being obsolete. Actually, I'm not sure if calling it "obsolete" is appropriate, because it has been wrong at the moment of posting it, due to wide browser support of `.addEventListener()`. I think that it received so many upvotes because in that time nobody cared about code quality. If you have any doubts, I explained broader why `.addEventListener()` is the best way to register event handlers [in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35093997/3853934).

Related:

- [How to deal with hugely upvoted, bad and outdated answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272570/how-to-deal-with-hugely-upvoted-bad-and-outdated-answers)
- [How to deal with a 'stolen' answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258558/how-to-deal-with-a-stolen-answer)
- [Answer edited to incorporate subsequent answer, and upvoted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280008/answer-edited-to-incorporate-subsequent-answer-and-upvoted)
- [How to deal with people editing their answers to incorporate other answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258183/how-to-deal-with-people-editing-their-answers-to-incorporate-other-answers)

Comment: "After some time" was only a few hours. You could have tried commenting to the answerer.

Comment: @BillWoodger I doubt that it would help.

Comment: You can doubt all you like. If you had tried, you'd know. Of course, if you'd waded into a comment with "code stolen" it would increase the chance of you being correct without trying. Anyway, we're still left with the highly-upvoted answer, and I'd guess we're stuck with that for a while.

Comment: if only the admin on stackoverflow did not delete the comments in there.. you will see how annoying he was.. as if he wants to change the accepted answer to his. But the question is already years old. There are a lot who added some answers and got upvoted. but they were not as annoying as he is. (my opinion). So I just copied his answer cause I thought he could not edit my answer and want to correct what is wrong. BUT this figured, he just want to get the accepted answer.

Comment: @Reigel Is there a reason you marked the post as protected about 45 minutes ago? Preventing competing answers is not a legitimate reason.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot that was just to prevent spam. I don't intend on competing... as what it says "This question is protected to prevent "thanks!", "me too!", or spam answers by new users. To answer it, you must have earned at least 10 reputation on this site."

Comment: @Reigel I see [a single answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34766597/176646) (deleted, 10k only) that would fall into that category (it looks like it should have been a comment). One answer in five and a half years is not enough to warrant protecting the question. See "When should I protect or unprotect a question?" in the [FAQ on Meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52764/what-is-a-protected-question).

Comment: @BillWoodger. He did tried commenting. but it was before I "copied" his answer. He "copy pasted" in all the answers given that his answer is the correct one. I did not respond cause it's an old post, anyone reading would get the idea. but one moderator showed up, so it got my attention. the comments between him and the moderator build up. We tried explaining to him what he could do. But now I understand, [he just want the accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350247/how-to-prevent-form-from-being-submitted#comment57737542_3350247)

Comment: No offense, but how would you write such a solution any differently?  Change the wording of the comment or omit the alert?

Comment: @cimmanon I wouldn't mind if he turned his answer into CW and replaced his solution with mine, instead of adding it as alternative.

Comment: It looks like a CW to me right now.  So what's the problem?

Comment: @cimmanon He is [still not convinced](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315446/code-stolen-by-highly-upvoted-outdated-answer#comment298890_315448) that his solution is obsolete. I don't think it would be good to completely change his answer, even if it's a CW.

Comment: @Gothdo *Theoretically your solution is valid (i.e. not obsolete), but it's commonly considered a bad coding practice. That's not just my opinion, but lots of JavaScript programmers agree with that.* mixed messages man. Is it or isn't obsolete?

Comment: @JustDoIt That depends on how you define *obsolete*. I think that this answer is obsolete, because today there are much better methods. This answer, despite being a poor solution, still works.

Comment: it's not good to downvote outdated answers, there should be other option, like mark it as outdated, etc.

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava When I hover over the downvote button, I see explanation what downvotes should be used for: "This answer is not useful". Are outdated answer useful? No. Even worse, they can often cause harm. So I downvote them. I may retract my downvote if the answer is edited to be up-to-date.

Comment: @Gothdo Ok that is a separate discussion probably no need to raise here, but downvoting is not fair to the person who gave a correct answer, albeit some time ago.

Comment: Related [How do we encourage edits to obsolete/out of date answers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/261817/213575)

Comment: That is the way with "open source" and there are many advocates of that here which means that anything posted here is free to plagiarise. Re down-voting, I see down-votes on my own questions by people who didn't read the question properly. As the author of the question I should be able to edit/correct that but I don't have the points... mainly because I spent them offering bonuses on questions that were never answered. Unfortunately, those points were not refunded. A better option would be to refund the bonus points in double for asking a question that all the experts here could not solve.

Comment: @WilliamK: _"As the author of the question I should be able to edit/correct that but I don't have the points"_ -- not sure what that means. The author of a post always is permitted to edit their own post. If you find you can't, that's a bug and you should seek help from the site admins to correct the problem. Do you have an example of a post that you authored and which you now cannot edit?

Comment: @PeterDuniho: I think WilliamK wants to 'edit' *down-votes on my own questions by people who didn't read the question properly*. No amount of reputation will let you do *that*.

Comment: @Martijn: _"No amount of reputation will let you do that"_ -- that's true. But his statement that _"I don't have the points"_ suggests that he's talking about some action he wants to take that _some_ amount of reputation _will_ allow. It seems to me a clarification from him will be more useful than speculation by any of us.

Comment: Like not being able to down-vote answers that were wrongly up-voted, especially those not even relevant to the question. Too many IT people speeed read, possibly because they are forever skimmimg. I posted one question and all three answers were out of the ball park. Then others up-voted those answers?

Comment: @WilliamK: not being able to vote until you get enough reputation is **by design**. Your comment complained about _"down-votes on my own questions"_ (the fix for that is to write better questions), and that you are unable _"As the author of the question...to edit/correct that"_. Please explain in what way you want to "edit/correct" the "down-votes on your own questions".

Comment: Re "write better questions" I suppose that it is inconceivable to encounter problems where there is no solution? In that case, as it turned out, there was no solution. The solutions offered were useless and unrelated yet they were up-voted by others who didn't read properly. We genuinely needed to solve it for our application to survive. As the person in need of a working solution and obviously the only person who understood the question, shouldn't I be able to down-vote the "stupid" answers so that the next people looking at the problem would not mistakenly assume that it had been solved?

Comment: @WilliamK I wonder how is your problem connected to my question.

Comment: @WilliamK: _"shouldn't I be able to down-vote the "stupid" answers"_ -- no, not without enough reputation. As I wrote, that's **by design**. It takes 125 reputation and you aren't there. It is not hard to reach 125 reputation. Many active users receive that much in a day. If you care enough about the quality of the site to want to be able to down-vote posts, then put enough effort into the site to earn the reputation you need to do so. As an added bonus: the effort you put in will _also_ improve the site, in and of itself.

Comment: Re "reach 125 reputation is not hard" is nonsense unless one works at it all day. Like most I have to earn a living and being on my own time, cannot afford to spend more than a couple of hours a week sifting though what are already answered questions which is best left to others wasting time paid for by their employers.

Comment: Asking questions is very different to answering. I ask questions because I have a genuine need for a solution. I think that most who answer have a need to earn points. It is only the latter who will have enough points in reputation to be able to manage their own questions.

Answer (score 88):

That's not ok; I rolled back the edit.

That said, it is possible that the user did this solely as a community service rather than for gaining points. Their answer is stuck to the top; they couldn't even delete it if they wanted, so they may have felt an obligation to keep the answer current. (The user doesn't appear to be in the habit of copying stuff from other answers, he looks like a solid contributor.)

Still, they have at the very least to provide proper attribution. Hitting the Community Wiki checkbox to prevent any further rep gain would also be a classy thing to do.

Comment: Thanks, I also considered rolling back the edit. However, this still doesn't solve the problem that the top answer is obsolete.

Comment: @Gothdo his -----

Comment: @Gothdo there's lots written about that type of situation. Nothing resolved.

Comment: `this still doesn't solve the problem that the top answer is obsolete`  yeah - that's kind of an unsolved problem on Stack Overflow in general

Comment: @BillWoodger Yes, that's why I asked this question.

Comment: @Pekka웃, just wondering, in this situation (not that I really care but), without "copy pasting" the answer, how would I update my answer to be more accurate to date? to make the answer accurate as much, the answer would be just the same as to Gothdo, so in general, how would someone do that? Cause it's like saying, we need a chair, but don't make a chair cause someone already did. :D

Comment: @Reigel Nobody said don't make a chair. They said don't steal someone else's chair and pretend you made it. You're required to cite material you get from other users. Not doing so is not only rude, but also a violation of the site's license.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot at this situation... I can't provide any other than his answer.. I could change some variables, but still, that would look and feel the same... like "copy pasting with style"... and on that day, there was a moderator, was he not doing his job? the one complaining now were suggesting a solution, I copied it, thought he just can't edit my post(which a few are doing)... moderator deleted all the comments for a reason. I just now wished he didn't.

Comment: @Reigel You're not listening. The copy/pasting is not the problem. The problem is that you didn't attribute where you copied from.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot just because he pointed it out (the answer), that doesn't mean he's the only one who knows it. And you're not getting what I'm up to. I said he's answer is the right one for the current time. I could write my own but it would look and feel the same as his. even though I'm not using "copy" "paste". So how can I make my answer accurate for the current time? *assuming I don't want to credit him for being rude..*

Comment: Sorry, that does not excuse you from giving credit where it's due. If you have a personal problem with the user whose answer you copied from, you are free to find another answer that you are happy to give credit to. *Intentionally* not crediting someone for their answer because you have a personal problem with them says a lot more about you than it does them.

Comment: @Reigel: If you developed code for your answer **without viewing** the answer below, you may do not leave the credit... But then you need to explain somehow, that this is not a plagiarism. And even explanation doesn't prevent your answer from downvotes. If your code **has been inspired** by the other answer, and you **doesn't want to change** the code, you need to leave the credit. `I could write my own but it would look and feel the same as his.` - but this would be OK. Change comment `// actual logic ...`, change alert message, and it will be *your own code*, so no credit will be needed.

Comment: I'm not really good at explaining myself, so I will not say more... cause either way, I still copied it and that's a fact I can't not change... I just felt that the message/post of the OP is just one sided.. *(moderator deleted all the comments there on the said Answer)* that's why I tried defending myself. I realized, I don't have to. Just like how I ignored his comment but a moderator commenting my answer got my attention. Anyway, I just want to help. My rep is just a bonus from what I learned in helping... Thanks for the heads up guys.. Will not do it again.

Comment: Nice demonstration of the horrors of having to support an SO answer for the rest of your natural life.  You have to be a damn fool to post answers in [javascript].  It has such a simple solution, write a new Q+A pair with the "modern" solution, vote as duplicate.

Comment: Pekka, about `the problem that the top answer is obsolete`. Is there a discussion on this somewhere? I too was wondering at some points how to answer/edit old questions and decided not to touch it because the community is so sensitive to the past here.

Comment: @user1803551 Yes, I already linked it: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272570/how-to-deal-with-hugely-upvoted-bad-and-outdated-answers

Comment: @Reigel simplest thing you could've done is add at the top of your post "*update:* **attention:** this answer is outdated. for an up-to-date answer see <<link>>".

Comment: @WillNess, I have thought about that... and then I realized, I don't have to... it's really the OP that says it is obsolete. But if you really know javascript, that is not obsolete.. There are ways to solve the said problem and I have given one of it. Whether it's best or not, it's still depends on one's opinion and the project/task to be accomplished. I've added there a link to an answer from another SO question that best describe it..

Comment: @Reigel Theoretically your solution is valid (i.e. not obsolete), but it's commonly considered a bad coding practice. That's not just my opinion, but lots of JavaScript programmers agree with that.

Comment: @Reigel If you think so (that your answer is not obsolete), then why did you bother to copy paste that content into your answer..?

Comment: @TJ because he insisted that he's answer is more accurate. I was not the one debating him but one moderator. So I tried copying his answer, and tried to comment and to asked him if that edited answer is good. BUT now, as you can see, there are no comments there.. there were I think 20+.

Comment: An easy way to avoid conflict in such a case is to mark the post Community Wiki, to prevent any future rep gain.

Comment: @Pekka웃 I just did after reading your answer earlier.. and thanks for bringing this to me up. Still, the OP is one sided. and why do you think he asked this kind of question now.. him and another moderator has their arguments about a month ago... so my question is why open it just now?

Comment: On my defense, I'm not really here on SO just to gain reps. I'm here to learn and help those who are also learning. I even rarely downvote. Try to check all my answers. Try to check all my comments. I do comments on answers which I think needs more build up. I suggest better answers if I have one(but not to the point that I'll push it to them). I communicate. That's how I think SO should be. Lots of COMMUNICATION. Not like this that you make a simple mistake, and then you're now the TURKEY on the table. I feel bad actually, I'm just trying not to care because it's not really what I'm here for.

Comment: Are comments permanently deleted? For some reason I feel like we're missing a huge chunk of context. All we have is the word of a user against the word of the other one.

Comment: @JustDoIt I assume the mods can see any deleted context on SO, including comments.

Comment: then how come there's no answer from one of them? @WillNess

Comment: @Reigel it is really simple. whenever you copy, you *must* give proper attribution. if you don't want to, don't copy, just give a link. Even if you re-write it, it is proper to mention where you got your initial inspiration.

Comment: @JustDoIt they avoid the excessive discussion?

Comment: well I think that there would be no excessive discussion if they end it with the context needed, cause yeah copying an answer is wrong, but so is pushing someone to the extent of annoyance(if it really happened, again its the word of a user against the word of the other one) @WillNess

Comment: there should be a way to mark outdated answers as such. No downvoting necessary.

Comment: @Reigel please try to bear with us:) You've made a mistake, and it happens to be of a kind that is very much frowned upon here (for good reason). Understandable that some people are furious (starting with OP here), but as Pekka said, you're a solid contributor to the site, and everyone makes mistakes. I believe essentially saying "Sorry everyone, won't happen again" (and then keeping yourself to that) is perfectly satisfactory in this situation, and it's the only thing you should be expected to do. That said, the CW is also a nice gesture and a display of good will.

Comment: Although I agree with you @AndrasDeak I still feel like we're a little biased since the only thing we have is a word against another word, I'd like to know if OP actually pushed one too many buttons on Reigel that his automatic response was "fine! here's your answer" which wouldn't help OP's case, you don't push people around. **BUT AGAIN** we lack of context and we're only presented what I think it's only one side of the coin

Comment: @JustDoIt I agree. I just wanted to note that this whole discussion, with Reigel trying to defend their stance, is likely a storm in a teapot. This is assuming that Pekka is right about Reigel being a valuable contributor to SO, but I've developed a habit of believing Pekka. The plagiarism has been done (for any reason, it doesn't really matter on an *objective* level), there's nothing anyone can do about it, we can only try to defuse the tension and make sure it doesn't happen again. The key is good will, regarding which there's less of an agreement here, as I see.

Comment: @Hans then watch the +50 questions on Meta accusing you in public of "repwhoring" and of "disgraceful elitist behaviour" roll in. Yes, this happened to me. Yes, I am still bitter about it.

Comment: You mean the one where you did **not** write a new Q+A pair and close-voted the new one instead of the old one?  No, that's not what I proposed.

Comment: @HansPassant sorry for being ignorant, but what is a `Q+A pair` ?

Comment: Question *and* answer.  Having one person write both is quite acceptable here.

Comment: ahh much more like you asked a question and give an answer @HansPassant? Then when a question asked similar to it, you will vote to close as duplicate? sounds fun.

Comment: Related [How do we encourage edits to obsolete/out of date answers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/261817/213575)

Comment: @Pekka웃 CW to prevent rep loss from downvotes, too, coincidentally...

Comment: Why roll it back! The whole point of this site is to put the best answer near the top. If the current answer is obsolete then why not copy the content of a better answer into the question. This is not a site for getting points the point of the site is to get the best answer to the people asking questions.

Comment: @LokiAstari points are hardly the issue here for anyone involved, but the right to ownership of the content you contribute is important. It's SO that is broken here because it's obscuring the now-correct answer, not the author's claim to their own content.

Comment: @Pekka웃: OK so SO is broken. That does not mean you should make the site worse. Why remove content that is good for users, simply because of an arbitrary hurt feelings issue. The code was contributed to SO under the CC license that allows re-use. The OA was re-using it because it made their answer better (which is allowed). Sure I agree that the OA should have quoted were it came from but that does not mean you should vandalize the site and make the answer worse.

Comment: @LokiAstari - Where is the incentive to write a higher content answer if it is just going to get taken by someone else? We are not ghost writers here, while the goal is for generating high quality content, that goal is only accomplished by the incentive for users to create it. Without user creation, we have nothing.

Answer (score 43):

Frankly, it seems to me that dragging Meta into this just wasn't useful.

I agree 100% with Pekka 웃's reply that the author's actions weren't entirely acceptable. But please note: the only thing wrong was the lack of attribution. This may or may not have been an intentional oversight, but regardless it was a minor one and easily rectified.

When you post to Stack Overflow, you grant license to anyone else to copy what you posted. It is simply not even *possible* for anyone to literally "steal" what you wrote, even if we accept the (debatable) idea that copyright violations are even technically a form of theft in the first place.

Now that you got Meta involved, the Q&A there is IMHO a mess, or at least messier than it really needed to be. You have the minimum 2000 reputation required to edit posts, so you could have **solved the problem yourself**, simply by adding the necessary attribution to make the copied code legal and ethical.

Had you done that, then the top-voted, accepted answer would itself include everything a person needed, in one place, to understand their options in solving that particular problem. And after all, **that's the whole point here**. To help other people. When possible, it is better to just fix the site in the furtherance of that goal, using the minimum collective effort possible (i.e. without engaging others at all, if you can).

In the future, please don't jump to conclusions and please don't ask the community to handle situations you are able to handle yourself. And please **do** remember that, properly attributed, whatever you post here is freely copy-able by anyone else.

Comment: I don't disagree that handling situations with the least possible amount of fuss is always the way to go, but 1:1 copypasta with the OP not giving an appropriate response arguably *is* a reason to get Meta, or mods involved. It's very hard not to interpret it as a hostile act, even though it probably wasn't meant that way.

Comment: I generally agree, but you missed my second point: "He should replace the outdated answer with an up-to-date solution, not add it as an alternative.". I asked this question because of two things: 1) using my code without any attribution and 2) outdated answer. The first problem has been solved now, but the second not.

Comment: If helping other people is the whole point here, then keeping answers up-to-date should be high priority.

Comment: @Pekka: _"It's very hard not to interpret it as a hostile act, even though it probably wasn't meant that way"_ -- that statement seems self-contradictory to me. If something **probably wasn't meant that way**, then how hard _really_ is it to interpret it as something other than a hostile act? It seems to me that the mere probability of it not being hostile is in fact strongly providing a way to interpret as something else. If the author rolled back the proposed edit, i.e. actively work _against_ attribution, then it would be worth getting a mod involved (but still not Meta).

Comment: @Gothdo: _"He should replace the outdated answer"_ -- frankly, on that we will have to agree to disagree. IMHO there is always a benefit to preserving what some might feel is an "outdated answer", as long as it's understandable as such. Not everyone will be using the latest (or even a very recent) version of the API and older answers are useful for that as well as historical perspective. _"keeping answers up-to-date should be high priority"_ -- nothing the other person did precludes that.

Comment: On the same post, even with attribution, other users shouldn't be copy pasting content. This answer is dangerous.

Comment: @Travis: _"users shouldn't be copy pasting content"_ -- cite, please. Something more than your own personal opinion. Because the SO model clearly supports copying of content, broadly. Indeed, guidance to users trying to improve a Q&A is (when needed) consolidate various differing and poorly-presented answers into a single well-presented one, copying content as needed (with attribution). I see absolutely no reason at all to dissuade people from using the existing copyright license exactly as intended: to allow free, attributed copying of content.

Comment: @PeterDuniho No offense, but I think only someone with good JavaScript knowledge can judge if this answer is useful or not. My solution [works in all, even obsolete browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=addeventlistener), excluding IE <= 8, which still supports proprietary `.attachEvent()` method. Actually, in the moment Reigel posted his answer, it already was bad and outdated, but in this time no one cared about code quality. It's absolutely no useful even for historical perspective.

Comment: @Gothdo: no offense taken. That said, while it is clearly your personal judgment that the answer was never of use, it is just as clear that a significant proportion of the community disagrees with that assessment. In any case, the question of the _quality_ of a question or an answer is clearly outside the scope of the Meta site; it would be a waste of time and resources for anyone to post to Meta every time they saw a post incorrectly upvoted. Your recourse is to downvote and move on. That's it.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I realize that you are relatively new to meta, so it makes sense you need other people to do your research for you. re: your request for citation. **The status quo is not "public domain"; attribution is already required.** and also **Stack Exchange does not claim exclusive ownership of content you submit**. So no, the whole point is not some laissez faire help everyone goal. There are rules. Suggesting that we should bypass them because it is your personal opinion flies in the face of the ToS and ignores a very large historical discussion that you allude to not once in this answer

Comment: @Travis: _"I realize that you are relatively new to meta"_ -- you're funny. I found the rest of your comment similarly amusing, in its complete irrelevance to what I've written here. Please, feel free to put more words in my mouth; you're welcome to all the straw men you like...whatever floats your boat.

Comment: You really shouldn't laugh off the need for citation - that is after all the topic here. The disregard to historical precedence with regards to meta discussion and any sort of citation seems to have been used in your answer as well.

Comment: _"You really shouldn't laugh off the need for citation"_ -- I'm not doing that at all. Your claim that I am is hilarious. Please, do keep amusing me.

Comment: An alternative would have been that users vote the new and more uptodate answer eventually to the top. Now basically we have two identical answers (and the second but more upvoted answer refers to the other answer), so where is the sense in copying. I this were suggested behavior I could just add another answer to each question and copying and referencing the current top answer. This would not be helpful. That's the reason why copying answers is not very useful. (And also the rep gets assigned to the wrong person even giving credit.)