# Should accepted answers on old questions be edited to reflect the "best answer"?

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer

I recently stumbled across [this accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5356149/1157054) to a popular Node.js question about how to check the version of V8 being used by Node.

The answer in its current state seems great, but after looking a bit more closely I realized that the answer has actually undergone [a major edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5356149/revisions) recently to make it match the [current highest voted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10264593/1157054) answer to the question (which prior to the edit was quite different from the accepted answer).

Was this a good edit? I'm a bit conflicted here, because while I do feel like the edit in question definitely made the answer *better*, it also deviates significantly from the OP's original intent and makes the more highly-voted answer below it seem redundant.

How should situations like this be handled?

---

Related:

- [Order highest upvoted answer before accepted answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/283456/1157054)
- [Deemphasise the accept mark if there's an answer the community strongly prefers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253752/1157054)

Comment: That is *very* inappropriate.  I rolled it back.

Comment: [That's not the first complete rewrite that that user submitted as an edit.](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/15387586/revisions)

Comment: [Code stolen by highly upvoted, outdated answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/315446/3853934) Related?

Comment: @hvd I flagged that one for mod attention, I'm surprised no-one else has

Comment: Well, that's nothing compared to the fate of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4129032/1083663). Sometimes SO feels more like Wikipedia.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

That edit was horrible and should be rolled back (and has been).

The votes on that answer were for the `node --version` version of the answer. The "Accepted" mark on that answer was for the `node --version` version of the answer. The answer provided an alternative that had been made invisible by the edit unless people felt like digging through the revision history.

> while I do feel like the edit in question definitely made the answer *better*

It did not make the existing answer any better. It provided a completely different answer. Whether that different answer is better is irrelevant:  new answers should be posted as new answers, not submitted as an edit to someone else's answer. Let the votes reflect which approach is preferred. The fact that the community votes for another answer than what the questioner has accepted is not something that needs to be fixed.